# import subpackage with libs in python

Tags: python, import, package

I use python script (e.g. script.py) and this script use third-party packages (sdk1, sdk2..)

First I put sdk1 and sdk2 packages into root directory:

```
/root
    script.py
    /sdk1
        ...
    /sdk2
        ...
```

In my script used `import sdk1` and it worked well.
Then i decided to change structure of my project:

```
/root
    script.py
    /libs
        __init__.py
        /sdk1
            ...
        /sdk2
            ...
```

And now `import sdk1` doesn't work. Also, don't work `import libs.sdk1`, `import sdk1 from libs`, `import * from libs`, `sys.path.append('/libs')` and ton other ways I tried.

I killed five hours trying to understand the magic of importing packages in python, but I did not find any right solution for my simple case.

Please, help me...

UPD: Python version is Python3.6

Comment: Did you try :  from libs import sdk1
Or you can directly import the functions or classes you need from sdk1: from libs.sdk1 import foo

Comment: Both doesn't work: `No module named 'sdk1'` and `No module named 'libs.sdk1'`

Comment: Can you delete your pycache directory and try

Comment: thank you for advice, but this didn't help